# Derivate $y(x) = y_0 +\int^{x}_{x_0}F(t,y(t))dt$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Let $\frac{dy}{dx} = F(x,y)$ be a bounded, continuously differentiable function which satisfies a Lipscitz condition. And let $y(x_0) = y_0$

I want to derivate the following

$$y(x) = y_0 +\int^{x}_{x_0}F(t,y(t))dt$$
to obtain the original function. How to do this?

The left hand side is of course just $\frac{dy}{dx}$ but what about the right hand side?

$\frac{d}{dx}( y_0 +\int^{x}_{x_0}F(t,y(t))dt) = \frac{d}{dx}y_0 +\frac{d}{dx}\int^{x}_{x_0}F(t,y(t))dt = 0 +  \frac{d}{dx}\int^{x}_{x_0}F(t,y(t))dt = $ 
$\frac{d}{dx} (F'(x,y(x)) - F'(x_0,y(x_0)))  $ Where $F'(t,y(t))$ is the primitive function of $F(t,y(t))  $ with respect to $t$

I think that $F'(x_0,y(x_0)) \in \mathbb{R}$ so $\frac{d}{dx} (F'(x,y(x)) - F'(x_0,y(x_0))) = \frac{d}{dx} F'(x,y(x)) -\frac{d}{dx}F'(x_0,y(x_0)) = \frac{d}{dx} F'(x,y(x))  - 0 = \frac{d}{dx} F'(x,y(x))$

I'm not sure how to show that

$$\frac{d}{dx} F'(x,y(x)) = F(x,y)$$

This is how far I got and I'm not even sure above steps are correct. Can anyone please help me solve this?

Comment: You're correct, $F'(x_0,y(x_0))$ is indeed a number. All above steps seem right too.

Comment: @cjferes Thats at least a start. Thank you! :) To the person downvoting me would you mind commenting on why you downvoted? Is there anything wrong with my question?

Comment: You can apply Differentiation under the integral sign (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign ), to get the conclusion much easier, witout primitives of $F$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the fundamental theorem of calculus
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\int_{x_0}^xF(t,y(t))\,dt=F(x,y(x)).
$$